# Using require.js with jsdom for server side rendering

Tags: node.js, requirejs, jsdom

```
var html ='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'+
                    '<html>\n'+
                    '   <head>\n'+
                    '       <meta charset="utf-8" />\n'+
                    '       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">\n'+
                    '       <title>foobunny rulez!</title>\n'+
                    '       <link rel=\'stylesheet\' href=\'/styles/app.css\' />\n'+
                    '       <script src="http://127.0.0.1:6789/scripts/lib/require.js"></script>\n'+
                    '   </head>\n'+
                    '   <body> \n'+
                    '       <script> \n'+
                    '           document.write("test");\n'+
                    '           require([\'/scripts/config.js\']);\n'+
                    '           require([\'/scripts/main.js\']);\n'+
                    '       </script>\n'+
                    '   </body>\n'+
                    '</html>';
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  FetchExternalResources   : ['script'], 
  ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
  MutationEvents           : '2.0',
  QuerySelector            : false
}
var window = jsdom.jsdom(html, null, {
  features: {
    FetchExternalResources: ["script"],
    ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
  }
}).createWindow();
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        res.send('<html>'+window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)+'</html>';
    }, 5000);
});
```

I have this small bit of code and require does end up adding the script tags to the head
(it adds `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="/scripts/config.js" src="/scripts/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="/scripts/main.js" src="/scripts/main.js"></script>`)

But the problem is that it doesn't seem to run any of the code within those scripts (which include more require statements). When the page loads everything runs perfectly, but I am trying to do server side rendering.

Should I be using absolute paths? I tried using `http://127.0.0.1:6789/scripts/main.js` and same for everything else but it doesn't seem to be working. What could be wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are not waiting long enough for the scripts to load. Try setting your timeout to 5000?

Comment: I did try that, still didn't work.

Comment: `feautres` doesn't look correct to me. `features`?

Comment: still same problem :\